# server make a txt file and client write it

Tags: java, networking, client-server

I have a project that has a server which creates an empty text file.

Once my client stops writing to this file, the server should read and display the results.

My problem is that the client is connecting to the server, but whatever text the client is sending is not being written on the server side. In addition, when I exit, the server doesn't quit.

This is what I have so far:

The Server

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Server {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
         BufferedWriter out;// = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C://Users//Vagos//Desktop//file.txt"));

         ServerSocket echoServer = null;
            String line;
            DataInputStream is;
            PrintStream os;
            Socket clientSocket = null;

    // Try to open a server socket on port 9999
           try {
               echoServer = new ServerSocket(55);
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
               System.out.println(e);
            }   
    // Create a socket object from the ServerSocket to listen and accept 
    // connections.
    // Open input and output streams

    try {
               clientSocket = echoServer.accept();
               is = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
               os = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
               out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C://Users//Vagos//Desktop//file.txt"));
    // As long as we receive data, echo that data back to the client.

               while (true) {
                 line = is.readUTF();
                 os.println(line); 
                 os.flush();
                 out.write(line);
                 out.flush();
               }
            }   
    catch (IOException e) {
               System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is my client:

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class client {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Socket smtpSocket = null;  
        DataOutputStream os = null;
        DataInputStream is = null;
        String strout;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
            smtpSocket = new Socket("localhost", 55);
            os = new DataOutputStream(smtpSocket.getOutputStream());
            is = new DataInputStream(smtpSocket.getInputStream());
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Don't know about host: hostname");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to: hostname");
        }

    if (smtpSocket != null && os != null && is != null) {
            try {
                do{
                    System.out.print("Write what the client will send: ");

                strout = in.nextLine();
                os.writeBytes(strout);}
                while(!strout.equals("exit"));
                os.close();
                is.close();
                smtpSocket.close();   
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                System.err.println("Trying to connect to unknown host: " + e);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("IOException:  " + e);
            }
        }
    }           
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

In your server

```
    // Open input and output streams

    try {
        clientSocket = echoServer.accept();
        is = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
        InputStreamReader ir = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ir);
        os = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C://Users//Vagos//Desktop//file.txt"));
        // As long as we receive data, echo that data back to the client.

        while (true) {
            line = br.readLine();
            System.out.println(line);
            os.println(line);
            os.flush();
            if( line != null ){
             out.write(line + '\n');
             out.flush();
            }
        }
    }
```

And about the 'exit' part of your client try after changing 
`while(!strout.equals("exit"));` 
to 
`while(!strout.equalsIgnoreCase("exit"));`

Hope this helps !!

Comment: yeas but when give exit is say nul nul nul nul and is not stop

Comment: @Βίκτοραςανδρεάδης, what says nul, server or client. Also in your server there is a `while(true)` code that needs to be changed. You have to end that loop, may be you can do it like this `while( line != null )`

Answer (score 0):

Today my teacher is upload a new project because he has make a false , the project i have to make is similar which the old but the client is reading or writing a txt with number from 0-911, The client is choice randomly what is make read o write if choice read show the numbers of txt if choice write he write randomly a number from 0-911 and stop if choice the 100.

i make it but nothing show me is stack.

sever

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Server {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
         BufferedWriter out;// = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C://Users//Vagos//Desktop//file.txt"));

         ServerSocket echoServer = null;
            int line;
            DataInputStream is;
            PrintStream os;
            Socket clientSocket = null;

    // Try to open a server socket on port 9999
           try {
               echoServer = new ServerSocket(55);
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
               System.out.println(e);
            }   
    // Create a socket object from the ServerSocket to listen and accept 
    // connections.
    // Open input and output streams

           try {
               clientSocket = echoServer.accept();
               is = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
               InputStreamReader ir = new InputStreamReader(is);
               BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ir);
               os = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
               out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C://Users//Vagos//Desktop//file.txt"));
               // As long as we receive data, echo that data back to the client.
              boolean ch=true;
              {
                   line =(Integer) br.read();
                 //  System.out.println(line);
                   os.println(line);
                  os.flush();
                   out.write(line+"\n");
                   out.flush();
               } while (line != 100); 

               os.close();
               out.close();
               br.close();
               clientSocket.close();

            }   
    catch (IOException e) {
               System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

client

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class client {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Socket smtpSocket = null;  
        DataOutputStream os = null;
        DataInputStream is = null;
        String strout;
        int number=0;
        Random rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
            smtpSocket = new Socket("localhost", 55);
            os = new DataOutputStream(smtpSocket.getOutputStream());
            is = new DataInputStream(smtpSocket.getInputStream());
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Don't know about host: localhost");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to: localhost");
        }

        int choice=2;//rand.nextInt(2);
        if(choice==1){
            int num=is.read();
            System.out.println(num);

        }
        else if(choice==2){
            try {
                do{
                 number=rand.nextInt(911);
                // System.out.println(number);
                os.writeInt(number);
                }while(number!=100);
                os.close();
                is.close();
                smtpSocket.close();   
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                System.err.println("Trying to connect to unknown host: " + e);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("IOException:  " + e);
            }
        }
    }           
}
```